# How do I limit the number of items in my ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to limit the `itemCount` of my `ListView` to a maximum of 5 and add the text "and more" if there are more items and only display the items if they are 5 or less. I've tried using `itemCount: 5` but that returns an error when the items are less than 5. How can I implement this?

```
ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: features.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "•  ${features[index]}",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }),
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
itemCount: features.length < 5 ? features.length : 5,
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try this

```
ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: features.length=>5?5:features.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "•  ${features[index]}",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }),
```

Answer (score 1):

you can return empty widget for index > 5

```js
ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: features.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return index > 5 ? SizedBox() : Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "•  ${features[index]}",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }),
```