# Reading specific items from json in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, parsing

Hi I have json containing almost 30 items I just waan display only 10 itmes in listview and on every time I refresh page should change (in other words random items) should be selected from the json.

Is ther any way and would be great If someone can show with example.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of what you have achieved so far and an example json?

Comment: What about something like ```itemCount: yourJson.length < 10 ? yourJson.length : 10,``` -- I found this on https://stackoverflow.com/a/68153079/6188976

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put json file in a folder called assets:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt6bj.png)

Add this to pubspec.yaml:

```
assets:
    - assets/
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuYPG.png)

main.dart file:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List items = [];
  int itemCount = 2;


  Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/items.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
    setState(() {
      items = data["items"];
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    readJson();
  }

  String randomItem() {
    int random = Random().nextInt(items.length);
    print(random);
    String item = items[random]["item"];
    
    List newItems = [];
    for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){

      if(item != items[i]["item"]){
        newItems.add(items[i]);
      }
    }
    items = [...newItems];

    return item;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Title"),
      ),
      body:

      items.isNotEmpty ? Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemCount: itemCount,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Column(
            children: [
              Text(randomItem()),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ): const Text("Loading..."),

    );
  }
}
```

Json file:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "item": "One"
    },
    {
      "item": "Two"
    },
    {
      "item": "Three"
    }
  ]
}
```

This picks two random items which are strings from the json file.

The itemCount variable can't be longer than the number of items in the json file. Change it to 10 if you want 10 different items.

Comment: What a great example thanks May I know  one last thing what a way to distinct the repeated items so that it should show only onece

Comment: @talalhabib Where items.removeAt(random); is, change it so it will remove all items with same value.

Comment: @talalhabib I updated the code so it will only show repeated items in the json file once.